# jQuery Sizzle call an error on selectors

Tags: jquery, sizzle

Why below code call error when i use sizzle:

```
var $myInput="#myForm input";

$($myInput+":checked").click(function(){
  ....
});
```

the `$($myInput+":checked")` selector return "[object Object] :checked".
But when I simply use the variable content like `$("#myForm input:checked")` work as carefully.

Thanks

Comment: `$myInput` is a string in your example so this can't happen. Are you sure this is the code that you're actually using?

Comment: That happens when you code `var $myInput = $("#myForm input");` not with a string.

Comment: [You can see that this is not true.](http://jsfiddle.net/yMnp8/) - Must be something else in your code.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I told jquery with sizzle. not pure jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$myInput` seems to be an object in your code, but is a string in your example code.

If you want to filter `$myInput` and only apply this event handler to `:checked` inputs, use something like this:

```
$myInput.filter(':checked').click(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Note that this handler is bound to elements that exist when `$myInput` was created, so this won't account for elements created later in time.